# Write a MIPS program that adds the values up and computes the average

Tags: mips

I have this assignment and am having trouble figuring out how to even start.

> Your program has a data section declared as follows:
>
> ```
> .data
> .byte 12
> .byte 97
> .byte 133
> .byte 82
> .byte 236
> ```
>
> Write a program that adds the values up and computes the average. Please use `$8` to
>   save the base address, `$9` to save the average, and `$10` to save intermediate results

I have done a little bit, but whenever I try to load the .asm file to QtSpim, it doesn't even run properly (ie. nothing gets loaded into the registers except for `$8`). I have been reading [this](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/assemblytutorial/Chapter-16/ass16_3.html) but have no luck at all understanding what to do still. Here is what I have:

EDIT: I worked it out after some more reading, and I think it's finally right. Or at least I'm on the right track, because I do get the right answer in $9.

```
## Assignment4_Question2.asm

         .data
b1:     .byte 12
b2:     .byte 97
b3:     .byte 133
b4:     .byte 82
b5:     .byte 236

        .text

main:   
        ori $13,$0,0x5      # Initialize 5 for division later on
        ori $12,$0,0        # Initialize $12 with 0
        lui $8,0x1000       # Save base address
        lbu $11,b1($8)      # Load byte 1
        addu $10,$11,$12        # Add byte 1 to $12; $10 is now sum
        lbu $11,b2($8)      # Load byte 2
        addu $10,$11,$10        # Add byte 2 to sum
        lbu $11,b3($8)      # Load byte 3
        addu $10,$11,$10        # Add byte 3 to sum
        lbu $11,b4($8)      # Load byte 4
        addu $10,$11,$10        # Add byte 4 to sum
        lbu $11,b5($8)      # Load byte 5
        addu $10,$11,$10        # Add byte 5 to sum
        divu $10,$13            # Divide sum by 5
        mflo $9         # Store in $9


## End of file
```

Comment: Why would you try to load from `12($8)` and `97($8)`? You haven't placed anything at those addresses as far as I can tell.

Comment: I was really confused at first, but I worked it out just now. I'll edit my post with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ori $13,$0,0x5      # Initialize 5 for division later on
ori $12,$0,0        # Initialize $12 with 0
lui $8,0x1000       # Save base address
lbu $11,b1($8)      # Load byte 1
addu $10,$11,$12        # Add byte 1 to $12; $10 is now sum
```

your addu this part does nothing, that is why you are missing the last addu at the very end.